# Perl utf8 decode and encode

Tags: perl, decode, encode

I've got a situation here trying to send and email with Mail::Sendmail from Perl    (cyrillic).

```
use Mail::Sendmail;
use Encode;
use utf8;

my $subject= "cyrillic message";
....
```

The problem is that I receive unrecogniseable symbols in my mail message.

I've already tried to use utf8, not to use utf8, I've tried decode and encode, decode_utf8 and so on (have read a lot, including Perlmonks discussions), but still I receive 2 types of unrecogniseable symbols in mails' subject or "Wide character in subroutine entry".

Added:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Mail::Sendmail;
use Encode;
use utf8;
use warnings;

my $subject= "cyrillic subject";
my $message= "cyrillic message";


my %mail = (
        To      => 'recipient@example.com',
        Subject => "$subject",
        From    => 'from@example.com',
        Message => "$message",
       );

sendmail(%mail) or die $Mail::Sendmail::error;

print "OK. Log says:\n", $Mail::Sendmail::log;
```

Comment: Can you post the error_log and the text in the email as it appears along with any warnings `use warning;` provides when run via the command line.

Comment: please provide code that actually demonstrates the problem!

Comment: As for `use utf8;`: If your source file is encoded using UTF-8, use `use utf8;`. If your source file is encoded using US-ASCII, don't use `use utf8;`.

Comment: If I use utf8 I receive "Wide character in subroutine entry at /usr/local/share/perl5/Mail/Sendmail.pm line 237."

If not, the message is sent, and I've got this "ÑÐ¾Ð¾Ð±ÑÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ". Also I've tried to encode it with Encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved without use utf8 and without use Encode.

I've added 'Content-type' => 'text/html; charset="utf-8"' header and everything become fine!